# Why my prev question "closed"

Tags: discussion

Does that mean no-one else can reply to it?

I really need answers to my questions in this original MOSFET question.

[How do I trigger this?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/664927/how-do-i-trigger-this)

Thanks.

Comment: You already got two helpful answers to your previous question. If you seriously want to get more detailed assistance, you need to provide more details of your complete project, and your question needs to be edited to include that. The additional info you supplied in comments should be in the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to reopen your question please look at the links:
[image]

In the link you will find the reason why your question was closed:

> Needs details or clarity - Sometimes we need more information in order
> to help solve your problem.
>
> ```
> This question should include more details and clarify the problem.
> ```
>
> Edit your post to be more specific about what you're looking for, and
> be sure to address any concerns that other users brought up in the
> comments.

The first problem is you didn't actually ask a question, that would be the first thing to do ask a good specific question that people can answer this is a Q&A site.

The next thing is provide helpful details like what you've tried and where you're stuck the more details you provide the easier it's going to be for people to answer your question. Otherwise we're going to close it to maintain the quality of the site that keeps users coming back to get good quality questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

A major problem is that you have asked a question which suggests that you do not know how to properly turn on the device BUT your real problem relates to producing a signal to drive it. You made a number of comments on Spehro's good answer to your original question which mentioned equipment and signals which you had not mentioned anywhere else previously.
You are very literally expecting people to know what you are thinking, what you are trying to do, what equipment you are using and how you are connecting it.  People here can not know any if this if you do not clearly and carefully explain it.

While the supplier's page lacks text documentation, the images of both sides of the pCBA are far better than average and allow the circuit to be determined.

Your problem overall is that you are trying to use another device that we do not know about and whose characteristics you poorly understands to switch the board, and are then trying to use the output to do something which you do not fully understand - and which we also do not know about.
(I base these statements on your comments to Spehro's answer).

---

Here is an edited version of the extra information that you provided:

> So, here's what I am trying to do, only now do I realise the output of this sound module

What sound module?

> needs to be inverted to go low when sound happens.
> Sound Detection Sensor Module Suitable for Arduino and Microcontrollers amzn.eu/d/iM3DgYp.

This is not a working link. We do not know what you wish to do with it.

> This goes into pin 2 of a delay off 555 monostable.
> build-electronic-circuits.com/555-timer –

Another non working link - and we do not know what you wish to use it for and  its overall circuit.

> I was able to get pin3 of 555 +ve, on trigger of +ve into pin2 from the sound board when sound occurred, don't ask me how.

"Don't ask me how" is a really bad approach to asking us to help you - rather, you need to provide a circuit if what you did, tell us why you did it and , very importantly, tell us what you are trying to achieve.

> Maybe it is the low pulse after the sound board realises there is no more sound.

Maybe.
We can only try to guess what that means.

> BUT, when pin 3 of the 555 was connected to the + in of that MOSFET
> board, and -in of the MOSFET board was connected to ground, the MOSFET
> stayed energised and wouldn't turn off. I am missing the small cap at
> pin5 of the 555 CCT though. –

We are missing a full circuit diagram and a full description of what you are trying to achieve overall and in detail.
NB - a description of HOW you tried may or may not be useful, BUT WHAT you wish to achieve is vital.

> Do I connect +in of that MOSFET board to 5V and invert pin3 of the 555 output and connect that to the -in of that MOSFET board? If so, do I need a R from +5V to +in to restrict current once inverted 555 pin 3 is active? Thank you all. –
> Mikmikmikmik
> 13 hours ago

Answer (score -1):

You bought some random piece of electronics without knowing what you are buying and you bought it from an online seller who does not give documentation to the sold products.

We can't tell you how something you bought works unless there is documentation how it works, and this is not a support site for random stuff bought from online shops that have no manuals.

Comment: Well that tells me I am in the wrong forum. Thank you. I will vacate and try somewher else.

Comment: @Mikmikmikmik You're in the right forum, you're on the wrong retail site LOL.  Also it helps to actually read stuff hand-written for you, and the close message which answers your question, and the help pages. But here.  Try https://boards.4channel.org/diy/

Comment: FWIW - while the page lacks text documentation, the images of both sides of the pCBA are far better than average and allow the circuit to be deternined. His main problem, though, is that he is trying to use another device whose characteristics he poorly understands to switch the board, and he is trying to use the output to do something which he does not fully understand. (I base those statements on comments to Spehro's answer - not an ideal way to do things :-( ).